# React Native: Starting IOS app size is 558.7MB, is this normal?

Tags: ios, typescript, react-native, size

The default files generated from npx react-native init {file_name} resulted in a 558.7MB app. This app is running on a physical device. Its also using typescript, but I don't think that should have that much of an effect. I have created react native apps in the past before but they were never this big, has something changed? Is this size normal now?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "-------",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't. May you at least provide your package.json to shee which modules are you using?

Comment: you talking about appSize(apk/ipa) or "npx react-native init {file_name} resulted in a 558.7MB app" modules?

Comment: @Ragnar appSize, I have the default starting app installed on my physical phone and tells me it is 558.7MB

Comment: there is no deps in your package.json that can increase the app that much. please check you build process again or try to clean build and rebuilt the app.